# Create and pass Model from HTML to Controller

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following

LegacyController

```
public ActionResult Index(Intranet.Models.LegacyModel legacy)
{
    return View(legacy);
}
```

LegacyView

```
@model Intranet.Models.LegacyModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = @Model.PageTitle;
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath(Model.URL));
```

LegacyModel

```
public class LegacyModel
{
    public string PageTitle { get; set; }
    public string URL { get; set; }
}
```

Within the _layout page I have menus. When a user clicks on a link I want from within the cshtml page create the LegacyModel object with the correct properties and pass it to the controller so the view is displayed.

Comment: try to redirect from the menu: `window.location.href = "LegacyController/Index?PageTitle=somePageTitle&URL=someTitle` The framework will map the params to the model

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out using @Html.Actionlink

```
@Html.ActionLink("Dec. 2014", "Index", "Legacy", 
new { PageTitle = "Newsletter Dec. 2014", URL = "~/Content/Documents/Newsletter/December2012/MainPage.htm" }, null)
```